# Trying to keep users in their home directory

Tags: webmin

I have created a user `brandon`. I am trying to keep `brandon` in his home directory (`/home/brandon/`), I would like him to be able to edit/delete/create folder and files, but I don't want him to go to `/home/` or anything else above his directory.

I have Webmin/Virtualmin, but I still cannot figure it out. Can anyone explain to me any configs  I need to edit or someway I can do it with Webmin?

Comment: Will brandon log into the machine (i.e. get a shell), or are you worried about ftp access or similar?

Answer (score 0):

Don't do it because there are some important files like `/bin`, `/etc`, `/var` which are necessary for normal users.

If you still want to, you just have to work a little bit with permissions.

Suppose you have the following users of your machine:

- `carla` - the owner of her home directory
- `lisa` - the owner of her home directory
- `root` - the superuser

Now the most important thing is, change the permissions.

First open terminal:

```
sudo -s

chmod 700 /home/user
```

It will give no permission to other users on your home directory (`/etc`, `/bin`, etc.) and that is what you were asking for.

Because by default it is `755`.

Type `umask 077` (without `sudo` helpful in your case)

This will give future files or directories `700` permission.

If you want to check it is working, check through terminal. Don't do it through GUI desktop.

Comment: don't do that if you want those users to ever log into your machine. Users need to be able to see contents such as /bin to execute anything. There is a reason why 755 is default.

Comment: I am using this for my friend, he is going to run a minecraft server with FTP/puTTy, he just needs to be able to put his files in, and start his server (eventually Multicraft, but I want to figure this out instead)

Comment: @user309285 You can remove read rights to /home/YOURUSER if you want, but your friend will need read rights to /bin and similar to start java for the minecraft server.

Comment: Not sure what happened, I didn't even get to what you said. I looked at his user in webmin and then I lost connection to the server with puTTy. I also can't connect to the FTP with any user excluding his user. Any solutions?